# Avoir le dos au feu et le ventre à table

Tags: grammaire, expressions, articles

Ce qui m'intéresse dans cette expression c'est que le mot **feu** est précédé par un **au** (et donc **à le**). Alors que le mot **table** est précédé par **à** et non pas par **à la**.

Pourquoi la même règle ne s'applique-t-elle pas? Auquel cas l'expression deviendrait soit:

> Avoir le dos au feu et le ventre à la table

Soit:

> Avoir le dos à feu et le ventre à table

Comment: "Avoir le dos à feu" couldn't ever be seen except saying "Avoir le dos à feu et à sang" but which has a completly different meaning :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selon le *Trésor de la langue française*, « [***à***](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A0) » peut, mais rarement, introduire sans article un nom ou un groupe nominal :

> À dans les locutions adverbiales de lieu. − À la différence des autres compléments circonstanciels, les groupes sans article introduits par *à* sont peu nombreux : **à** bord, **à** côté, **à** distance, **à** droite, **à** gauche, **à** main gauche, **à** bon port, **à** proximité, **à** quai, **à** terre, **à** table.

Dans cette liste, on retrouve **à table**, mais pas **à feu**, ce qui explique assez bien la différence de traitement entre les deux substantifs.

Answer (score 4):

Sans avoir plus de données sur l'histoire de cette expression, difficile de répondre, mais j'imagine que la différence vient du fait qu'on a ici deux expressions :

- *Être dos à + GN* où *GN* est un groupe nominal complet, ici *le feu*
- *à table* qui est une expression figée qui désigne le fait d'être assis devant une table voir *passer à table*, *être à table*…

Ce qui est inhabituel ici c'est que c'est le ventre qui est à table, au lieu de tout l'individu, mais l'image est assez claire.